# nodeJS / Electron renders pages slower than Chrome

Tags: node.js, performance, electron

We are building a restaurant POS system with Electron (nodeJS 7.4.0/Electron 1.6.11). For a POS system, speed and reliability are the 2 most important requirements, and after having spent some time building the app we are no longer certain if Electron is the right software for us.

*Speed* seems to be the main issue. For testing, we've built an app that only shows 2 "hello world" html pages without any additional javascript or any other assets. When running on a modern iMac, there's a short delay when switching between the pages and the app flashes white between the page loads. On an older PC running Windows 7, it takes up to 1 second to simply switch between these 2 pages. Load time on the mac is 167ms for an empty "Hello World" page.

Now, running these 2 pages directly in the Chrome browser, the pages load instantly, without any loading time and no white flash between page loads. 40ms in the network inspector.

The difference in speed is a lot more significant with more complex pages loading Javascript files and images (even though everything is loaded locally)

What's the reason for the much longer loading time in Electron vs Chrome, what could we be doing wrong ?

[image: Screenshot of Hello World page loading on Electron]
[image: Screenshot of Hello World page loading in Chrome]

Comment: Have you compared with nw.js? They both work a little different internally (especially the page and node integration).

Comment: Not yet. From your experience is that faster with rendering html pages. I just really wonder why Chromium is so much slower than Chrome

Comment: Have you also tested it with `nodeIntegration: false` just to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: setting nodeIntegration to false didn't make any difference, but setting sandbox to true did. Load time for the Hello World page is down from 160ms to 4ms (so it now loads instantly). What's sanbox doing and why is it faster in sandbox mode ?

Comment: From the official docs: 
sandbox Boolean (optional) - If set, this will sandbox the renderer associated with the window, making it compatible with the Chromium OS-level sandbox and disabling the Node.js engine. This is not the same as the nodeIntegration option and the APIs available to the preload script are more limited.

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#class-browserwindow

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare `NodeJS 7.4.0 (with v8 5.4.500.27)` and `Electron 1.6.11` with the current version of v8 in last version of Chrome.

NodeJS, v8 and Electron has a lot of performance implementations along the time in each version update even the RAM management is better.

I recommend to upgrade the version of `NodeJS` and `Electron` and test again your results.

Additionally, if you serve an html with http on a NodeJs server it will run faster than in Electron due to the fact that electron does a lot of things behind the scenes to serve you the content. Similarly, as long as you use the most recent versions the time gap should be lower :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two step when show a page in nodejs:
first: setup a chrome envirment, includes webview engine and v8 etc...
second: run the chrome native process, like normal chrome in window. In common situation, the first step running by user.
Therefore, maybe pre-setup chrome process when nodejs or Electron when starup the App, that will shrink time.
That is like mobile app optimize way.