# Electron window title takes a few moments to load (shows project's name before loading)

Tags: javascript, performance, user-interface, npm, electron

When I run my code using `npm start`, it takes a few moments before the title of the `main_window` is fully loaded. Here's a GIF demonstrating it:

[image: wtf]

This is my code:

```
const electron = require('electron')
const url = require('url')
const path = require('path')

const {app, BrowserWindow, Menu} = electron

let main_window

app.on('ready', function() {
    main_window = new BrowserWindow({})
    main_window.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'main_window.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }))

    Menu.setApplicationMenu(null)
})
```

Before the title, which I specified in my `main_window.html`, loads, it shows the name of the project, which I specified in my `package.json`. I don't think the content of these two files is relevant, but here they are anyway:

`main_window.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>7Watchlist Data Grabber</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Another Collection of Web Crawlers</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "datagrabber",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Another Collection of Web Crawlers",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/amirashabani/DataGrabber.git"
  },
  "author": "Amir A. Shabani",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/amirashabani/DataGrabber/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/amirashabani/DataGrabber#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

Is it something I have to accept? I don't think this is normal behavior.

Edit1: Setting `sandbox` to `true` or running app with `npm start --no-proxy-resolver` (as suggested by [@Mr. Polywhirl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55921613/6282576)) doesn't seem to make a difference:

[image: sandbox and --no-proxy-resolver]

Comment: Set [**`sandbox`**](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/sandbox-option) to `true`? via [nodeJS / Electron renders pages slower than Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45156262/nodejs-electron-renders-pages-slower-than-chrome)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it something I have to accept? I don't think this is normal behavior.

It's normal behavior, as the lifetime of your BrowserWindow is not the same as the lifetime of your HTML(DOM). You can load URL into BrowserWindow multiple times and perform a lot of other tasks not related to HTML.

So I don't think it's reasonable to expect that the BrowserWindow will follow the DOM state of your HTML. However you can make it that way

Use [`'dom-ready'`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#event-dom-ready) or [`'ready-to-show'`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#event-ready-to-show) events to avoid showing anything before the HTML is completely loaded (including original window title)

[From docs](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#using-ready-to-show-event)

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
let win = new BrowserWindow({ show: false })
win.once('ready-to-show', () => {
  win.show()
})
```

Comment: In case you're using `win.maximize()` then you have to include right before `win.show()`

Answer (score 1):

Another option besides `sandbox = true` and `--no-proxy-resolver`, as mentioned by Mr. Polywhirl, is to [directly set the title](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions). The given title will then be used until the page has been rendered and Chromium is able to display the HTML's `<title>` content.

```
main_window = new BrowserWindow ({
    title: "7Watchlist Data Grabber"
});
```

This solution will not prevent your code from accessing NodeJS APIs as it doesn't create a sandbox. However, the sandboxed approach is considerable as it is also more secure.

Answer (score 0):

Set [**`webPreferences.sandbox`**](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/sandbox-option) to `true` for your `BrowserWindow`.

**Reference:** [nodeJS / Electron renders pages slower than Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45156262/nodejs-electron-renders-pages-slower-than-chrome)

```js
main_window = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    sandbox: true
  }
})
```

---

#### Edit

Another suggestion is running the app with the `--no-proxy-resolver` flag.

See: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/12895